# Unity Mirror, Client is not executing damage Command

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

I have a script on the Player that gets its target by clicking on them. I check if the players auto attack cooldown is 0 and if the player is in range. After that it should run a Command and damage the enemy mob.

This only happens as it is intended on the host and not on client.
And if I remove the enemy != null check in the CmdDamage function the client just disconnects.

public class PlayerAttacker : NetworkBehaviour

```
public EnemyScript enemy;

public float timer = 0;
public float timerMax;

private void Start()
{
    timer = timerMax;
}
private void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
        return;       

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 mousePos2d = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos2d, Vector2.zero);
        if(hit.collider != null && hit.collider.GetComponent<EnemyScript>() != null)
        {
            enemy = hit.collider.GetComponent<EnemyScript>();
            enemy.target.SetActive(true);
        }         
    }
      
    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        timer = 0;
        BasicAttack();
    }
    else if(timer > 0)
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
private void BasicAttack()
{
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(enemy.transform.position, transform.position);
    if(dist < 2.5f)
    {
        GetComponent<NetworkAnimator>().SetTrigger(Animator.StringToHash("sword slash"));           ///SEND TRIGGERS OVER NETWORK
        CmdDamage();
        timer = timerMax;
    }
}
[Command]
private void CmdDamage()
{
    if(enemy != null)
        enemy.TakeDamage(5);
}
```

public class EnemyScript : NetworkBehaviour

```
    [SyncVar(hook = "OnHealthChanged")] public float currentHealth;   //ADD HP BARS INGAME
public float maxHealth;

[SerializeField] public HealthBar healthBar;

public override void OnStartServer()
{
    currentHealth = maxHealth;
}
public void TakeDamage(float amount)
{
    if (!isServer)
        return;

    currentHealth -= amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your OnHealthChanged -hook implemented? With SyncVars that are hooked, you have to assign changed variable inside hook method. In your case, you have to assign a new value for currentHealth inside OnHealthChanged.

Now your currentHealth is updated only on server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.